# How to determine the size of a non-installed python package?

Tags: python, pip

I don't have much space left, and I am tempted to install python libraries.

I would like to know how big a python library is before installing is (just to know how much extra space to request if I don't have enough).

Is there a way to do that, e.g. using `pip`?

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible using `pip` as far as I know. But if the package is hosted on PyPI you can append `/json` to the URL to view more details, including file size.

For example, visit https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json and have a look at the entries in the `releases` key. The `size` of each release tells you how big the download would be.

Note that this tells you the download size, not the size after installing (as a package may request additional dependencies for installation, after decompressing the archives, and so on). So your question may be difficult to answer, prior to installation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `requirements.txt` file use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# by rubo77: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278901/1069083

mkdir -p /tmp/pip-size
for i in $(pip-sync -n requirements.txt|tail -n +2); do
  echo -ne "$i:\t"
  wget --quiet -O /tmp/pip-size/$i https://pypi.org/pypi/$i/json
  cat /tmp/pip-size/$i | jq 'last(.releases[])'[].size | paste -sd+ | bc > /tmp/pip-size/$i.size
  cat /tmp/pip-size/$i.size | awk '{$1=$1/1024/1024; print $1,"MB";}'
done
echo -e "--------\ntotal:"
cat /tmp/pip-size/*.size  | paste -sd+ | bc | awk '{$1=$1/1024/1024; print $1,"MB";}';
```

output example:

```
ninja:  1.4366 MB
numpy:  120.735 MB
opencv-python:  724.788 MB
pillow: 137.695 MB
scikit-image:   7.46707 MB
torch:  4772.73 MB
torchvision:    153.842 MB
--------
total:
5918.69 MB
```

Comment: On OSX this script did not work until I changed the two `paste -sd+` to `paste -s -d '+' -` and then upon running it adds up the size of all of the libraries on my machine.  Putting a blank requirements.txt file does the same.

Comment: Try the commands in that line one by one and see where it differs from Linux

Answer (score 1):

This is my script i'm currently using

(based off the excellent package walking code from [How to see pip package sizes installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266159/how-to-see-pip-package-sizes-installed/34267468))

## Steps :

1. create a python script to check all currently installed pip packages
2. create a shell script to create a brand new python environment and install package to test
3. run shell script
4. profit :)

## Step 1

create a python script called `tool-size.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import pkg_resources

def calc_container(path):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size

def calc_installed_sizes():
    dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]

    total_size = 0
    print (f"Size of Dependencies")
    print("-"*40)
    for dist in dists:
        # ignore pre-installed pip and setuptools
        if dist.project_name in ["pip", "setuptools"]:
            continue
        try:
            path = os.path.join(dist.location, dist.project_name)
            size = calc_container(path)
            total_size += size
            if size/1000 > 1.0:
                print (f"{dist}: {size/1000} KB")
                print("-"*40)
        except OSError:
            '{} no longer exists'.format(dist.project_name)

    print (f"Total Size (including dependencies): {total_size/1000} KB")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_installed_sizes()
```

## Step 2

create a bash script called `tool-size.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# uncomment to to debug
# set -x

rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs/tool-size-tester
python -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/tool-size-tester
source ~/.virtualenvs/tool-size-tester/Scripts/activate
pip install -q $1
python tool-size.py
deactivate
```

## Step 3

run script with package you want to get the size of

`tool-size.sh xxx`

say for truffleHog3

```
$ ./tool-size.sh truffleHog3

Size of Dependencies
----------------------------------------
truffleHog3 2.0.6: 56.46 KB
----------------------------------------
smmap 4.0.0: 108.808 KB
----------------------------------------
MarkupSafe 2.0.1: 40.911 KB
----------------------------------------
Jinja2 3.0.1: 917.551 KB
----------------------------------------
gitdb 4.0.7: 320.08 KB
----------------------------------------
Total Size (including dependencies): 1443.81 KB
```

Comment: Wouldn't this tool download all those packages to determine the size? That wouldn't be very helpful if you have nospace left.

Comment: was think you would run this on a different non space compromised machine :)

that way the poor server / embedded device doesn't need to use any space

Comment: activate and deactivate does not work when running the script.  `./tool-size.sh: line 8: ~/.virtualenvs/tool-size-tester/Scripts/activate: No such file or directory` `./tool-size.sh: line 11: deactivate: command not found`

Comment: This script may fail if the package can't be parsed because an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8970) with package's conflict, I solved an issue like that by search/uninstall the guitly package using `grep -r 'MSG_ERROR_OUTPUT' 
 /[PATH_TO_ENV]/envs/[ENV_NAME]/lib/python[VERSION]/site-packages`, [here](https://gist.github.com/bitsnaps/2402619cf7b39cfc42b109f7ae19cc01) is an updated version show package size.