# pip show command doesn't shows any info

Tags: python, pip

I've tried to show package info with commands like

```
c:\Python36-32\Scripts>pip show sphinx
c:\Python36-32\Scripts>pip show --verbose sphinx
c:\Python36-32\Scripts>pip show --verbose google-api-python-client
c:\Python36-32\Scripts>pip show google-api-python-client
```

as described here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/#pip-show , but no one of this commands showed any info:

[image]

Why it doesn't work and what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` shows info for installed packages:

> Show information about installed packages.

You need to install the package to view info with `pip show`.

You can however exploit this [`pip dry_run` bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33243972/3125566), and show info for the package installed from the previous `dry_run`:

**pip_show.bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_DIR='/tmp/venv'

function dry_run (){
    if [ ! -d "$TMP_DIR" ]; then
            virtualenv --quiet /tmp/venv
    fi
    /tmp/venv/bin/pip install $1 --quiet
    /tmp/venv/bin/pip show $1
}
dry_run "$@"
rm -rf $TMP_DIR
```

---

```
$ . pip_show sphinx
New python executable in /tmp/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Name: Sphinx
Version: 1.5.3
Summary: Python documentation generator
Home-page: http://sphinx-doc.org/
Author: Georg Brandl
Author-email: georg@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: Jinja2, babel, requests, docutils, alabaster, snowballstemmer, Pygments, six, imagesize
```

But the time to setup  a virtualenv and do the dry run could just outweigh the benefit of viewing the package info with pip in your terminal than with a browser.

Comment: Hi! I don't want install any package without review, what files that package will install on my machine. How to show info about package without installing that package on my PC?

Comment: Not sure there is any way to do that, at least not with `pip`. You can search for the package on PyPI without pip: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov If you're on a Unix machine, you can try out the script

Comment: What is virtualenv ? I am Windows user, how to implement such script in Windows? Thank you!