# How to find size of all packages installed in my pip virtual env

Tags: python, pip

I have a pip virtual env with many packages installed. I would like to see the size of each package if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: Navigate into it and look at the size of folders in `site-packages`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see pip package sizes installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266159/how-to-see-pip-package-sizes-installed)