# Why do I get such a big Docker image (6.9GB)?

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

My Docker image is too big and I don't know how to get it smaller.
I want to build a Docker image for my streamlit app with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.0-slim

WORKDIR /app
RUN python -m venv venv

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY .env .env

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
   apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
EXPOSE 8501

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "streamlit", "run"]

CMD ["Home.py", "--server.port=8501"]
```

The problem is definitely the layer installing the requirements:

```
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
903fc6d91fc0   18 minutes ago   CMD ["Home.py" "--server.port=8501"]            0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      18 minutes ago   ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit" "run"]                  0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      18 minutes ago   COPY . /app # buildkit                          42.3MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      18 minutes ago   EXPOSE map[8501/tcp:{}]                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      18 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install --no-cache-dir -…   6.73GB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      18 minutes ago   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1                          0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      38 minutes ago   COPY .env .env # buildkit                       987B      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      38 minutes ago   COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt # b…   3.28kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      38 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c python -m venv venv # buildkit   17.2MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      20 hours ago     WORKDIR /app                                    0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
```

And here is my requirements.txt file

```
aiohttp==3.9.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
altair==5.2.0
annotated-types==0.6.0
antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3
anyio==4.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.2.0
azure-core==1.30.0
azure-storage-blob==12.19.0
backoff==2.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
blinker==1.7.0
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
coloredlogs==15.0.1
contourpy==1.2.0
cryptography==42.0.4
cycler==0.12.1
dataclasses-json==0.6.4
dataclasses-json-speakeasy==0.5.11
Deprecated==1.2.14
distro==1.9.0
effdet==0.4.1
emoji==2.10.1
entrypoints==0.4
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
Faker==23.2.1
favicon==0.7.0
filelock==3.13.1
filetype==1.2.0
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fonttools==4.49.0
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.2.0
gitdb==4.0.11
GitPython==3.1.42
grpcio==1.60.1
grpcio-tools==1.60.1
h11==0.14.0
h2==4.1.0
hpack==4.0.0
htbuilder==0.6.2
httpcore==1.0.2
httpx==0.26.0
huggingface-hub==0.20.3
humanfriendly==10.0
hyperframe==6.0.1
idna==3.6
importlib-metadata==7.0.1
iopath==0.1.10
isodate==0.6.1
Jinja2==3.1.3
joblib==1.3.2
jsonpatch==1.33
jsonpath-python==1.0.6
jsonpointer==2.4
jsonschema==4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
kiwisolver==1.4.5
langchain==0.1.8
langchain-community==0.0.21
langchain-core==0.1.25
langchain-experimental==0.0.52
langchain-openai==0.0.6
langchain-pinecone==0.0.2
langdetect==1.0.9
langsmith==0.1.5
layoutparser==0.3.4
lxml==5.1.0
Markdown==3.5.2
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
markdownlit==0.0.7
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
marshmallow==3.20.2
matplotlib==3.8.3
mdurl==0.1.2
more-itertools==10.2.0
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.5
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
networkx==3.2.1
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.26.4
omegaconf==2.3.0
onnx==1.15.0
onnxruntime==1.15.1
openai==1.12.0
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.2.0
pdf2image==1.17.0
pdfminer.six==20221105
pdfplumber==0.10.4
pikepdf==8.13.0
pillow==10.2.0
pillow_heif==0.15.0
pinecone-client==3.0.3
portalocker==2.8.2
prometheus_client==0.20.0
protobuf==4.25.2
pyarrow==15.0.0
pycocotools==2.0.7
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==2.6.1
pydantic_core==2.16.2
pydeck==0.8.1b0
Pygments==2.17.2
pymdown-extensions==10.7
pyparsing==3.1.1
pypdf==4.0.2
PyPDF2==3.0.1
pypdfium2==4.27.0
pytesseract==0.3.10
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.1
python-iso639==2024.2.7
python-magic==0.4.27
python-multipart==0.0.9
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
qdrant-client==1.7.2
rapidfuzz==3.6.1
referencing==0.33.0
regex==2023.12.25
requests==2.31.0
rich==13.7.0
rpds-py==0.18.0
safetensors==0.4.2
scipy==1.12.0
six==1.16.0
smmap==5.0.1
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.5
SQLAlchemy==2.0.27
st-annotated-text==4.0.1
streamlit==1.31.1
streamlit-camera-input-live==0.2.0
streamlit-card==1.0.0
streamlit-embedcode==0.1.2
streamlit-faker==0.0.3
streamlit-image-coordinates==0.1.6
streamlit-keyup==0.2.3
streamlit-toggle-switch==1.0.2
streamlit-vertical-slider==2.5.5
sympy==1.12
tabulate==0.9.0
tenacity==8.2.3
tiktoken==0.6.0
timm==0.9.16
tokenizers==0.15.2
toml==0.10.2
toolz==0.12.1
torch==2.2.0
torchvision==0.17.0
tornado==6.4
tqdm==4.66.2
transformers==4.37.2
typing-inspect==0.9.0
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2024.1
tzlocal==5.2
unstructured==0.12.4
unstructured-client==0.18.0
unstructured-inference==0.7.23
unstructured.pytesseract==0.3.12
urllib3==2.2.0
validators==0.22.0
watchdog==4.0.0
wrapt==1.16.0
yarl==1.9.4
zipp==3.17.0
```

My system is a MacBook M1 and this is my Docker build command:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --platform=linux/amd64 -t app:v1.0.0 .
```

Comment: Which of the three commands in that step you identified is responsible for an unexpected amount of data?

Comment: Hi, you have a lot of dependencies. It doesn't seem so, but it adds up quickly. I would consider removing those you don't absolutely need. Also, I think that `python:3.10.0-alpine` is smaller than `python:3.10.0-slim`. You would need to replace `apt-get` with Alpine's `pkg add` though. However, this would shave off just a couple hundred MB at best.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't know what you mean. I'm a docker beginner and I tried to figure out on how to get a smaller image, bcs. it seems that 6GB docker image is considered quite big. It takes very long to build and to upload. As mentioned above, it seems like the problem is connected to the python dependencies and the way they are integrated in the docker image.

Comment: @marek But how do I distinguish between the dependencies I need and which I don't? I mean, these packages are all the ones I needed to install for my app to run.

Comment: BTW: You're killing any performance using `--no-cache` for the build! This flag has its uses, but it shouldn't be used for every build after every miniscule change!

Comment: @Dom R. That's a great question. I am not sure how you got this list. Was it using `pip freeze` command? If so, it would include all the dependencies you've installed on your computer. I guess I would start here. Create a `venv`, and install necessary dependencies using `pip`, then use `pip freeze`. If you need all of them, then maybe consider removing some functionality that these provide. BTW, I found a guide for reducing Docker size for your https://pythonspeed.com/articles/smaller-docker-images/ (not mine, but it looks useful).

Comment: @marek Thank's for the link, I already look into it yesterday, but will give it a second view. Yes I used pip freeze, but with my venv activated. So it should only list the dependencies which are in my venv right?

Comment: Checkout [how-to-see-sizes-of-installed-pip-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266159/how-to-see-sizes-of-installed-pip-packages) and see if you can remove some big packages or find an alternative.

Comment: @marek Even if alpine is smaller as a base image, I would not recommend using it. It seems to kills build perf and requirements end up taking more space:  https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: Looking at some other questions, it seems like PyTorch is just that big.  There's not anything obviously wasteful in the Dockerfile, especially once you've confimed that all of the space is being taken up by the `RUN pip install` step.

Comment: @Teemu Risikko Interesting, I see this for the first time. I didn't have any problems when using Alpine Linux for building Docker container, though, I usually use other programming languages. It may still be relevant, for example if the cost of images stored in some repository (e.g. ECR) is a concern. But I guess I'll stop recommending it in general :D